# Was bedeutet »am Absaufen«?

Tags: meaning

Beispielsatz:

> »Wir waren bei der Arbeit gerade am Absaufen und ich habe an nichts mehr gedacht.«

Heißt es »sehr beschäftigt«? Hat es etwas mit Alkohol (Saufen) zu tun?

Comment: Es kann beides heißen, aber der übertragene Sinn ist naheliegender

Comment: @Emanuel in general *Absaufen* is not in combination with alcoholic beverages. moreover *Absaufen* is a colloquial form of *Ertrinken* --> drown.

Comment: @Vogel612 Aber gerade in diesem Beispiel kann es sich eben auch auf Alkohol beziehen.

Comment: @Toscho I strongly doubt that. Whenever it's about alcohol, there will not be any prefixes or suffixes added. Literally and figuratively. pure ethanol is always the best ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 Ich halte es für ein generisches Präfix `ab-`. Insofern kannst du es vor jedes Verb setzen, wo es inhaltlich halbwegs Sinn macht.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eigentlich müsste es heißen:

> Wir waren gerade *beim* Absaufen.

Die Variante mit *am* bedeutet das Gleiche, ist aber (noch) umgangssprachlicher. Wird gerne die rheinische Verlaufsform genannt, ist in begrenztem Maß aber auch in anderen Sprachregionen üblich, während die Extremvariante („am Text am Schreiben“) nur im Rheinischen gebräuchlich ist.

Absaufen ist umgangssprachlich für Ertrinken, hat also nichts mit Alkohol zu tun. Saufen ist genau genommen ja auch nur das Trinken der Tiere, während es beim Menschen umgangssprachlich dann Alkoholtrinken bedeutet.

Die Bedeutung ist also, dass man am Ertrinken vor Arbeit war – also sehr viel zu tun hatte und daher zu nichts anderem gekommen ist. Je nach Situation heißt es daher auch, dass einem das Wasser bis zum Hals steht (dann ist die Situation kritisch) oder dass man einfach nur, ja, sehr beschäftigt ist.

Comment: Mit "beim" klingt es, als ob es gewollt ist. Ich habe so meine Zweifel, dass die Rheinische Verlaufsform und "beim" dasselbe heißen.

Comment: Also den Satz "Wir waren gerade beim Absaufen" würde ich, für sich alleine als "beim Ab-Saufen" lesen, also wirklich beim Trinken.

Comment: @Emanuel: *im* bzw. *beim* bilden standardsprachliche Verlaufsformen und *am* bildet eine umgangssprachliche Verlaufsform.

Comment: @PMF: Du meinst, die haben sich bei der Arbeit komplett besoffen? Das bezweifle ich dann doch eher ;) Nein, Absaufen bedeutet schon (und nur) Ertrinken, während die "Ab-Verb"-Formen extrem umgangssprachlich sind.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Also wenn man sich während der Arbeit komplett betrinkt, ist wohl Umgangssprache angebracht ;-) Ansonsten stimme ich dir zu.

Comment: @PMF, am Anfang des Abends ansaufen, am Ende dann absaufen? :)

Comment: Ich verstehe „am Absaufen“ so, dass man vielleicht auch nur kurz davor ist, zu ertrinken, während „beim Absaufen“ impliziert, dass man wirklich dabei ist, zu ertrinken.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Das steht aber auch zusammen mit "gerade", und das impliziert, ob nun *am*, *beim* oder *im* dabei steht, dass man gerade dabei ist.

Comment: im Absaufen begriffen... igitt, das ist ja eloquente Gossensprache...

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Klar, bis zum Absturz.

Comment: Danke für eure Kommentare. Der Autor dieser Aussage trinkt zwar gerne Bier, er ist allerdings kein Alkoholiker, deswegen tendiere ich eher zu der Lösung Ertrinken/ertrunken:)

Comment: +1 für die rheinische Verlaufsform. Manche würden vielleicht sogar sagen: `Ich bin ab ab am saufen.` vgl. `Die Kuh am Schwanz am raus am ziehen` - siehe http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/post-an-den-zwiebelfisch-die-kuh-am-schwanz-am-raus-am-ziehen-a-351745.html

Comment: "Saufen ist genau genommen ja auch nur das Trinken der Tiere" - tatsächlich? Also so, wie "fressen" das "essen" der Tiere ist? Das war mir so bislang nicht geläufig, und die Aussage "Die Ziege frisst Gras und trinkt aus dem Eimer." klingt für mich deutlich natürlicher als "Die Ziege frisst Gras und säuft aus dem Eimer." Ist es nicht eher so, dass "saufen" im nicht-alkoholischen Sinn vielmehr ungeachtet des Subjekts bedeutet, dass *große Mengen* an Flüssigkeit getrunken werden?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Es geht mir genauso wie dir, Fressen & Trinken klingt für mich auch bei Tieren natürlicher. Man gewöhnt sich aber erstaunlich schnell daran, wenn jemand konsequent Saufen für das Trinken der Tiere verwendet. Das ist zum Beispiel in Jurassic Park der Fall (das Buch, nicht der Film, der ist ja nur ein kurzer Auszug). Und es hat nichts mit der Menge der Flüssigkeit zu tun. Das ist ja im Grunde der Witz: Saufen und Fressen sind die Begriffe für Tiere, verwendet man sie hingegen beim Menschen, sind sie abwertend/übertrieben gemeint.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Ok, wobei der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/saufen) diese Interpretation noch mit "besonders von größeren Tieren" qualifiziert, was natürlich gewissermaßen eine Tendenz hin zu größeren Flüssigkeiten (als sie z.B. bei einer Rennmaus vorkommen) impliziert.

Comment: Das ist richtig. Allerdings behaupte ich, dass der Duden sich da auch an die sprachliche Nutzung anpasst, die, wie du selbst geschrieben hast, eher eine Tendenz zum Trinken hat. Wobei eine Ziege halt auch schon keine Rennmaus mehr ist und die Grenze daher fließend wäre. Auf der anderen Seite brauchen ja angeblich alle Tiere, egal ob Rennmaus oder Elefant, durchschnittlich 21 Sekunden, um ihre Blase zu entleeren... Daraus lässt sich ein Rückschluss bezüglich der Relativität der Flüssigkeitsmengen auch beim Trinken/Saufen zu ihren jeweiligen Tieren schließen ;)

Answer (score 5):

`Am Absaufen` kann in diesem Kontext als Situation verstanden werden, in der man den Überblick bzw. die Kontrolle verliert. Der Betroffene gewinnt den Eindruck, seine gerade zu erledigenden  Arbeiten nicht mehr bewältigen zu können.

Das kann an der Menge der Arbeit liegen oder an ihrer Schwierigkeit.

Answer (score 4):

"Am Absaufen" hat nichts mit Alkohol zu tun, sondern kommt aus der Bergmannssprache und bedeutet, dass die Grube/der Stollen ungeplant mit Wasser volläuft.

[Siehe auch hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/absaufen)

Umgangssprachlich wird es oft auch auf Hochwasser und andere Überschwemmungen angewendet (z.B. "das ganze Haus soff ab") . Im Zusammenhang mit hoher Arbeitsbelastung kenne ich es nicht, aber man könnte das schon so sagen.

Comment: Auch im Nautioschen wird es verwendet: _Der Kahn säuft ab_ : Das Schiff geht unter.

Comment: Der Duden sagt da eigentlich nur, dass "absaufen" in der Bedeutung, dass etwas mit Wasser volläuft, aus der Bergmannssprache kommt; *nicht*, dass das Verb insgesamt aus der Bergmannssprache kommt oder die Bedeutung mit dem Stollen die einzige wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde, richtig idiomatisch ist nur "Wir waren gerade am Absaufen" (Das Wasser stand schon in Mundhöhe, ein Bild für in Arbeit ertrinken). "Beim Absaufen" wäre zwar das Gleiche, aber ich würde hier nicht "beim" sagen.

Mit "am" wird angedeutet, dass es gleich zu Ende ist, man geht unter. "beim" deutet mehr an "immitten" einer Tätigkeit" wie in "Die Kinder waren beim Spielen". Aber streng gehabt wird diese Unterscheidung nicht.